# Вернуться к предыдущему запросу в php

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysql

Добрый день!
У меня такой вопрос 
есть страница "дисла" с вывод данных из таблицы

```
<? foreach ($disla as $item):?>
<td><input name="nomer_vagona" type="submit" value="<?=$item->number_vagona ?>" /></td>
                    <td><?=date("d.m.y", strtotime($item->disla_date))?></td>
                    <td><?=$item->time ?></td>
                    <td><?=$item->op ?></td>   
                    <td><?=$item->dpr ?></td>
    <? endforeach;?>
```

при нажатии на кнопку номер вагона появляется история этого вагона в другой вьюшке "история вагона".
так вот мне нужно реализовать кнопку назад, чтобы после "истории вагона" я могла вернуться на результат выборки "дисла", грубо говоря как в окне браузера кнопка назад(только такая же кнопка внутри меню сайта). как это можно реализовать? джаваскриптом либо хранить запрос. просто представления не имею.
За ранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать на **JS**:

```
javascript:history.back()
```

*Но пользователь может открыть страницу в новом окне.*

На **PHP** можно получить адрес, с которого пришли:

```
$backLink = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

*Этот параметр может быть запрещен в браузере пользователя.*

Comment: спасибо, воспользовалась js, получилось то что нужно!

Comment: замечательно :)